# UIAlertView's delegate method alertViewCancel: does not get called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

The `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol states the following:

```
// Called when we cancel a view (eg. the user clicks the Home button). This is not called when the user clicks the cancel button. 
// If not defined in the delegate, we simulate a click in the cancel button 
- (void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView;
```

However, I have a `UIAlertView` that is displayed and when I now hit the Home Button in the simulator, the method `alertViewCancel:` does not get called. Please note that the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method gets called when I touch a button on the AlertView so the delegate is hooked up correctly.

Is this a bug on Apples side or is it me, or maybe the Simulator?

**Edit:**

I currently work around this issue by listening to the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification where I do the following to dismiss the AlertView:

```
[self.currentAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:NO];
[self.currentAlert release];
self.currentAlert = nil;
```

Comment: Are you doing something in clickButtonAtIndex which would override any calls to alertViewCancel?

Comment: Can you show the code that creates alert view?

Comment: @carbonbasednerd Good question, but the method `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` does not get called when I hit the HOME Button. I worked around this issue by listening to the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification (I updated my post with this bit of information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called when the system actually *cancels* your alert view. Your alert view isn't cancelled anymore when your application goes into the background as unless your app is evicted by the flotsam process, when you become foreground again, your alert view will popup again. I presume, though I don't know for sure, that if flotsam kills your process, you'll get this delegate call as part of the teardown sequence.

The documentation is probably a bit misleading on this point. It used to be the case that home button presses canceled alerts, but it's not always the case any more.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. This means that on a "pre-multitasking-device" the method would probably get called, since the `UIAlertView` would really be cancelled, and therefore not be shown again. But who is this `flotsam`? :-)

Comment: `flotsam` is the system process that eats applications when the system wants more memory. When memory pressure on the device is high, flotsam picks a backgrounded application, and sends a memory warning. If the application doesn't free up enough memory, `flotsam` kills it off. It's a kindred spirit to `watchdog`, the system process that kills unresponsive applications. The name's a pun on "flotsam and jetsam", terms for things floating around that aren't being used.

Comment: Just for completeness, I should clarify that flotsam will attempt to recover memory by sending warnings first, then killing the *biggest* background offenders rather than killing apps in age order. It's a really good idea in iOS 5 to free up memory when you receive a warning and get your resistant footprint down as low as you can. You won't get another chance, and if you become small enough, you're more likely to get skipped over for culling in favor of a higher usage app. Not being killed gives a huge advantage in perceived "loading" times.

Comment: So I keep on using the approach with `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` to dismiss the `UIAlertView` when the App goes inactive.

Comment: @Besi Yup, that sounds like the best plan to me